# Creating planispheres from the perspective of nearby objects

Tags: observational-astronomy, night-sky

I'm attempting to create a set of [reasonably] astronomically accurate planispheres from the perspective of observers positioned at the north or south poles of various nearby celestial objects. So basically looking out with a 180˚ FOV of each celestial hemisphere.

Using Stellarium and some information I found on this site, I've been able to piece together some decent enough reference images that I should be able to use for this project.

Example: Earth's northern celestial hemisphere

[image]

I've been able to make them for objects as far out as Pluto. But... I want to go farther. Let's say Alpha Centauri A.

As far as I know Stellarium doesn't allow you to mount yourself to an object outside of the greater Solar System. This is unfortunate.

I discovered Celestia, which I thought would be the answer. Using Celestia one can fly out to distant stars and wow, what a view!

[image]

The problem is that Celestia can't bump the FOV past ~124˚. Manually forcing it to 180˚ causes the program to glitch out.

And here I am. I just can't seem to figure out a way to do this. I've been stuck on this for some time now.

Does anyone know of any software or other tools that may be useful for this project? Celestia has shown me that it's possible. I feel like I'm really close.

Comment: 1) the stars look very similar from Alpha Centauri's planets as they do from Earth (w/ the exception of the Sun and Alpha Centauri itself) because 4.5 light years isn't a large distance astronomically speaking. Also, do we really know Alpha Centauri A's north pole? (we might, but I wasn't sure). Most complete way = take a catalog of stars and plot.